# Extract text from a Wordnik API URL in Google Sheets

Tags: import, google-sheets, wordnik

Can anyone explain how to import/extract a particular field from the following url into Google Sheets:

[Wordnik URL](http://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/pretty/phrases?limit=5&wlmi=0&useCanonical=false&api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5)

I'm guessing there is an IMPORTXML query that could do it, but it doesn't have the nodes that IMPORTXML usually uses to import that. Instead the code looks like this:

> [{"mi":6.720745180909532,"gram1":"pretty","gram2":"much","wlmi":18.953166108085608},{"mi":6.650496643050408,"gram1":"pretty","gram2":"good","wlmi":18.469078820531266},{"mi":9.839004198061549,"gram1":"pretty","gram2":"darn","wlmi":17.298435816698845},{"mi":7.515791105774376,"gram1":"pretty","gram2":"cool","wlmi":15.515791105774376},{"mi":8.233704272151307,"gram1":"pretty","gram2":"impressive","wlmi":15.210984195651225}]

So if Cell A2 has the URL that produces this as the code, how do I get B2 to give me the text after "gram2" (in this case, "good", "darn", "cool" and "impressive").

Thanks

Tardy

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a workaround but it is kind of messy. I'd still like an answer to the question, but for reference and in case it's of use to anyone I'll post it here:

Using =IMPORTDATA(E10) (where E10 is the cell with the URL in) gave me an array (I guess based on .csv principles) that I could then manipulate using some other tools, like regexreplace, to get at the relevant bits of text.